# How to fix "E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/."

Tags: partition, kali-linux, disk-usage

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
root@kali:~# df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           406M  7.0M  399M   2% /run
/dev/sda6        12G   11G  480M  96% /
tmpfs           2.1G   78M  2.0G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8        58G  114M   55G   1% /home
tmpfs           406M   37k  406M   1% /run/user/0
```

Comment: I don't know what `/dev/sda7` is, but you have lots of free space in `/dev/sda8`. Maybe resize your `/home` and move the freed space to `/`?

Answer (score 55):

If you're getting this error in a Docker container - it helped me to do a

```
docker system prune
```

Comment: ran this and i got 22 Gigs back 

Comment: If using minikube, do `minikube ssh` first to get into the VM.

Comment: Extra clarification... I received the error when issuing `docker build` (which is perhaps what @barfuin meant) and his/her suggested fix (`docker system prune`) did indeed solve the problem for me (got past previous point of failure).Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Fixing this largely depends on where the cruft has built up.

1. Start with unnecessary packages and apt cache:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
df -h
```

2. Use `du` to look for cruft in `/var` and `/var/log`.

```
sudo du -xh --max-depth=1 /var
sudo du -xh --max-depth=1 /var/log
```

If a lot of space is consumed by `/var/log`, I usually cleanup old log files with:

```
# Note, change +30 to the number of days you want to keep.
sudo find /var/log -mtime +30 -type f -delete
```

Other directories probably need to be handled differently.

3. Lastly, check if running processes have a lock on files pending deletion.

```
sudo lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'
# If your system doesn't have lsof installed:
sudo apt install lsof
```

If there are large files pending deletion, you may need to restart the process or daemon with the lock.

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't `apt-get clean` free enough space, there is a faster way, than resizing filesystems:

```
mv /var/cache/apt/ /home/
ln -s /home/apt/ /var/cache/apt
```

Make sure you there is no /home/apt directory beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

I think var/cache/apt/archives is a bit full soo

`apt-get clean packages`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was getting this error

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

While installing a package inside a Debian container.The problem got resolved by going to Docker:

```
Dashboard -> Settings -> Resources
```

and increasing the disc image size from 60G to 80G. This is a temp solution, you will need to clear unused images/container/volumes to reduce the disc space

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem, but in my case, this problem went away by just rebooting the system. I guess my computer has commutated very much temporary files.

If nothing works, you might give rebooting a try!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen quite often when using micro SD as a hard drive for Raspberry Pi.

```
raspi-config --expand-rootfs
```

That works for Raspberry Pi OS but if you're using your Pi for Kali you need

```
kalipi-config --expand-rootfs
```

It seems every time I use a fresh installation of Kali for the Pi, it won't upgrade without using the command. Rarely though do I require using it on a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Rasp Pi imager it auto partitions boot and bootxx and leaves the rest free not allocated.

The simple fix is:

1. Open GParted
2. Within GParted

   - Go down to the second partition
   - Click the move/resize option
   - Allocate the free space to the second disk.
   - Press the check at the top.
3. In a terminal

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this error message showed up on a raspberry pi zero-w with fresh install of Raspbian 10 Buster:

```
You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

The other answers here are valid, but this fresh image had no significant previous packages for removal, so removing them didn't help.

solution (1): **use raspi-config --> Advanced --> Expand Filesystem**

this will [expand the root filesystem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39824) to use the entire sd card.

solution (2): or [from the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195836):

```
raspi-config --expand-rootfs
```